# what is more performant equal or instanceof?

Tags: java, performance

Which method is performanter to use?

equals:

```
public boolean hasSellByDate(Object item) {
  if ("Pear".equals(item.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

instanceof:

```
public boolean hasSellByDate(Object item) {
   if (item instanceof food.Pear) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

What differences do these two methods have and what disadvantages are there in each case?

Comment: they are not the same

Comment: better use instanceof (null, child classes); probably faster too.

Comment: Putting semantic differences aside (the two methods are not exactly the same, but that's probably irrelevant in your case), use the tool that has been invented for your use-case. In this case, you should use `instanceof`. It's probably faster, but then again - it probably does not matter in your case.
Also, your code can be simplified to `return (item instanceof food.Pear);`.
And, ultimately, instead of any logic depending on `instanceof` checks, you should use polymorphism. But that's a little more advanced concept, you'll get there in time, don't worry about it too much.

Comment: so actually if you do this, are you aware you might get other classes named Pear in other packages and this will tell you that they are the same? Not to mention that string comparison is surely less performant then some built in Java class functions?

Comment: @maslan you think "String comparison" is not some built in Java (class) function ?

Comment: @Stultuske this is a shortcut, obviously it is build in but it is just a string comparison char by char instead of some binary operation

Comment: @sulox32 it depends on which gives you the correct result for your requirement. those two methods don't provide the same functionality, so there is no "better", they're both good, providing they do what they should do, and both bad, if they don't do what you expect of them

Comment: @Stultuske by that logic, a method that fails unit-tests is not "better" or "worse" than a method that passes, because they don't provide the same functionality! We are assessing the two approaches against what they are meant to achieve. I think the intention is clear enough from the question.

Comment: @sdgfsdh a method that fails unit-tests. How do you know the problem is with the method, and not with the test? Sure, we can look at the "intent" of the question, which is open for interpretation, or, in our responses, we can also take into account the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

The second one if far superior because the first can be broken by refactoring, and the type-system will not let you know.

You should also be aware that the first method will not work for subclasses of `Pear`, should you have any. Even worse, it might be confused if you have multiple classes called `"Pear"` in different namespaces.

As for performance, you will need to benchmark, but I would expect the second to also be faster, since `instanceof` is a single opcode on the JVM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

Comment: not to mention the 1st one also includes string comparison operations

Comment: "The second one is far superior" ... since both methods don't do the same, how is it far superior?

Comment: @Stultuske they are not exactly the same functionally speaking, but given what the author clearly intends to do, the 2nd will be correct in more cases. The reasoning is in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add other two snippets to your list. So four options would look like below.

Please mind that all four options are functionally different!

**#1**

```
public boolean hasSellByDate(Object item) {
  if ("Pear".equals(item.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**#2**

```
public boolean hasSellByDate(Object item) {
  if (item instanceof food.Pear) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**#3**

```
public boolean hasSellByDate(Object item) {
  if ("food.Pear".equals(item.getClass().getName())) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**#4**

```
public boolean hasSellByDate(Object item) {
  if (item.class == food.Pear) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Performancewise (at least in OpenJDK HotSpot JVM):

- `#4` is the fastest
- `#2` and `#3` would be close, `#2` is likely to be fastest after round of JIT compilation
- `#1` could be real performance bottleneck especially in multi threaded environment

`Class.getSimpleName()` could be unreasonable slow due to global critical section and string manipulation. I've seen it once being a real performance bottleneck. Method was used for formatting log messages.

Stylewise, I would recommend `#2` and `#4` dependent on functional needs.

And to stress one more time, **all four options are functionally different!**